# Mongodb c# driver aggregate out

Tags: c#, mongodb

I wrote an aggregation query using fluent api of C# driver for MongoDb and I would like to insert the results inside a collection. For this purpose there is the **Out** aggregation pipeline stage. It automatically creates an **ObjectId** for each document but I would prefer using an int field which is already in the document. Is it possible ?

I tried creating a specific class for the results of the aggregation:

```
class MyResultClass {
[BsonId]
public int Key {get; set;}
...
```

The aggregation query is aware of the type of the result, I put a '**Project**' stage which explicitly allocates **MyResultClass** objects this way:

```
Project(el => new MyResultClass {Key = el => el.ProductID ...})
```

Unfortunately the inserted documents have their own ObjectId, so I cannot subsequently read them using MyResultClass which specifies a different **_id**

Comment: Instead of `$out` try using the `$merge` stage (it also creates an output collection like $out, but has more features). How does your aggregation create the new `_id` (with integer value)?

Comment: The integer _id I want to use, ProductID, is the key in a previous group stage